# Order of module search in cmake find_package command with the NAMES option

Tags: qt, cmake

CMake offers a command option `NAMES`:

```
find_package(<package_name> NAMES Qt5 Qt6 ...)
```

What is the logic in processing the passed names?

In the example above, do we get the first discovered package and stop?

What happens if we have several packages installed?
Do we get the last discovered one as a result?

An example in the Qt's documentation tells us that the search is stops after finding the first available library. CMake's documentation does not explain anything. On one particular Linux machine I observed the behavior when we continued search until we touched the last available package in the list.

Answer (score 0):

The logic, as you say, is we get the first discovered package and then stop. Because of this, I prefer to list the newer version of Qt first, as it has a lower chance of being available when using system packages on older systems.

```
find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
```

For `NAMES` to work you only need one component: `Core`. Passing multiple components may result in undesired behavior. The Qt version found will then be stored in the `${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}` variable. All other modules can be found after, with another call to `find_package`, like so:

```
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Quick Svg)
```

To force use of a specific Qt version, you can set the `QT_VERSION_MAJOR` variable yourself...

```
set(QT_VERSION_MAJOR 6)
```

Or pass it as an option with automatic detection as a fallback:

```
option(QT_VERSION_MAJOR "Set Qt major version")
if (NOT QT_VERSION_MAJOR)
    find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)
endif()
```

Comment: I am not sure it works the way you describe. I have Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. Both Qt5 and Qt6 are installed, CMake 3.22.1. If I keep just one of the names in the list, the corresponding version is discovered. If both names are on the list, in whaterever order, CMake always uses Qt5